# Prove that every regular subset of $a^nb^n$ is finite

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

How to prove that every regular subset of $L=\{a^nb^n \mid n\ge0 \}$ is finite?

I know that every finite language is regular, and it's not true that every regular language is finite.

I also know that $a^n b^n$ is non-regular language.

I can find examples of finite regular subsets of $L$, for example $\{\epsilon, ab, aabb\}$, but how do I prove that all regular subsets of $T$ are finite?

Comment: Your question doesn’t make sense. What is “a regular language in language L” supposed to mean?

Comment: (If something looks too obvious to prove, try contradiction.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple application of the pumping lemma. Suppose that $L'$ is an infinite subset of $L$. Given $p$, since $L'$ is infinite, there exists some $n \geq p$ such that $w = a^nb^n \in L'$. Let $w = xyz$ be a decomposition of $w$ such that $|xy| \leq p$ and $y \neq \epsilon$. Then $y = a^t$ for some $t \neq 0$, and so $xy^0z = a^{n-t}b^n \notin L'$. Therefore $L'$ is not regular.

One might be tempted to think that this argument generalizes to every $L$ whose non-regularity can be proved using the pumping lemma. However, this is incorrect, as the example of $L \cup c^*$ shows.

This raises the following intriguing question:

> For which infinite languages $L$ is it the case that all regular subsets of $L$ are finite?

Comment: My guess to answer your question: if none of the strings are pumpable, so if each string of $L$ can be used with the pumping lemma to show $L$ irregular. If any string of $L$ is pumpable, then all its pumps form a regular subset.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that if your language contains $a^nb^n$ and $a^mb^m$ for n <> m then after parsing $a^n$ and parsing $a^m$ you end up in different states. (Proof is trivial).

If there are infinitely many different n, m then the number of states cannot be finite.